# Use -parameter Java argument in IntelliJ

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jackson, gradlew

So we're trying trying to execute individual test cases in IntelliJ. Because we are using the jackson-module-parameter-names module, we must compile our project using the `-parameters` flag. All test cases are working fine when we execute them through Gradle, but when we run an individual test in IntelliJ, they are not working (because of the missing `-parameters` argument.

When running through intellij all the tests depending on jackson serialization are failing.

How does one fix this?

We already tried to make it work by setting the following setting in intellij to `-parameters`

```
Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler > Additional command line parameters
```

In gradle we have a similar setting which does work.

```
subprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << '-parameters'
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to delegate actions (or tests) to Gradle? Check out the options under (`Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle > Runner`).

Comment: Can you check the [build.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) file? Do you see the `-paremeters` option added there?

Comment: @lu.koerfer Tried this, sadly does not seem to solve the issue. @CrazyCoder this file doesn't seem to update every time I execute build through IntelliJ or manually through Gradle, but so far the log file does not contain the `-parameters` option anywhere.